# Probability arrangements

Tags: probability

> A sports committee of four is to be chosen from a group of nine students, made up of three boys and six girls. Calculate the expected number of boys on the sports committee of four.

I get in order to calculate expected value you have to find the probability of there being $0,1,2,$ or $3$ boys and then compute:

$$0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+\cdots$$
But, how do I calculate the individual probabilities?

Answer (score 2):

There are $9$ student, and therefore there are $\binom{9}{4}$ equally likely ways to choose a committee of four.

There are $\binom{3}{0}\binom{6}{4}$ ways to choose $0$ boys and $4$ girls, so $\Pr(X=4)=\frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{9}{4}}$.

There are $\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose $1$ boy and $3$ girls. Now you can calculate $\Pr(X=1)$.

The probabilities $\Pr(X=2)$ and $\Pr(X=3)$ are found in a similar way.

**Another ways:** Imagine choosing the people one at a time. Let $X_1=1$ if the first person chosen is a boy, and let $X_1=0$ otherwise. Define $X_2$, $X_3$, and $X_4$ similarly. Then the number $X$ of boys is given by $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$.

By the **linearity of expectation** we have $E(X)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3)+E(X_4)$.

To calculate $E(X_i)$, note that $X_i=\frac{3}{9}$ for all $i$, so $E(X_i)=\frac{3}{9}$.

It follows that $E(X)=4\cdot \frac{3}{9}$.

**Remark:** The method we used in the second solution is very powerful, and lets us compute expectations even when probabilities are difficult or impossible to compute. The method is called the *Method of Indicator Random Variables*.

Comment: Thanks for the really good explanation

Comment: You are welcome. I have added a "fancier" method that at this stage you are probably not expected to use, but that may be worth knowing about in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are $\binom{3}{k}\cdot\binom{6}{4-k}$ ways of choosing a team with $k$ boys.

How many ways are there of choosing a team of $4$ people (without restrictions)?

Can you combine the two lines above to find $P(X=n)$? (The answer should be yes.)

Answer (score 0):

A way to calculate these probabilities is through a combinatorics which would be as follows 
$$Pr(X=i)=\frac{{3 \choose i}{6\choose 4-i}}{{9\choose4}}$$